# Nginx failed (13: Permission denied) when start rails with unicorn

Tags: nginx, unicorn

My rails app runs on server with `Unicorn` and `Nginx` , but after configure Nginx and start it, i got the error:

```
2015/08/03 15:43:44 [crit] 13951#0: *1 stat() "/home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/current/public//index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 123.185.144.80, server: 52.74.148.194, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "52.74.148.194"
2015/08/03 15:43:44 [crit] 13951#0: *1 stat() "/home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/current/public/.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 123.185.144.80, server: 52.74.148.194, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "52.74.148.194"
2015/08/03 15:43:44 [crit] 13951#0: *1 stat() "/home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/current/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 123.185.144.80, server: 52.74.148.194, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "52.74.148.194"
```

here is nginx_myapp.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name 52.74.148.194;

 root /home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/current/public;
 location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I googled hours but still can't solve this. I am guessing if any path typos, and not sure why the error message with "`public//index.html`", not "`public/index.html`" Any hint? thanks!

Nginx runs with user '`nginx`' like below:

**EDIT:**

```
$ groups nginx
nginx : nginx ec2-user
groups ec2-user
ec2-user : ec2-user wheel
```

Permissions of paths: (current)

```
current]$ ls -l
total 76
drwxrwxr-x 8 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:06 app
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:08 assets_manifest_backup
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:26 bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  830 Aug  3 14:06 Capfile
drwxrwxr-x 6 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:08 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  153 Aug  3 14:06 config.ru
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:08 db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1720 Aug  3 14:06 Gemfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 5262 Aug  3 14:06 Gemfile.lock
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:06 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:35 log
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:08 public
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  249 Aug  3 14:06 Rakefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  478 Aug  3 14:06 README.rdoc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    8 Aug  3 14:07 REVISION
drwxrwxr-x 8 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:06 test
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:35 tmp
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug  3 14:06 vendor
```

public: (I changed to 777 even)

```
ls -l
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1564 Aug  3 14:06 404.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1547 Aug  3 14:06 422.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1477 Aug  3 14:06 500.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   47 Aug  3 14:08 assets -> /home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/shared/public/assets
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user    0 Aug  3 14:06 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user  202 Aug  3 14:06 robots.txt
```

Change nginx user in nginx.conf from 'nginx' to 'ec2-user' solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that nginx is run under proper user (`user ...` directive in main nginx config file), and then make sure that `/home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/current/public/*` files are accessible for that user (i.e. they belong to the same group as the user, and have read permission on them).

You also need to have +x permission on every directory down your path. You could see permissions with `ls -l` in your terminal, and then just do something like that if they lack:

```
chmod g+x apps
cd apps
chmod g+x mybest
cd mybest
chmod g+x current
cd current
chmod g+x public
cd public
chmod g+r *
```

**UPD**. As found out down in comments, nginx runs fine under `ec2-user` username (`user ec2-user` in config). Most likely there are restrictive permissions (no "+x"/"+r" for group on directories) for `/home` and/or `/home/ec2-user`. Personally, I see nothing wrong having nginx run under `ec2-user` username. Or you could move your Rails application for example to `/var/www/my_app`, setup permissions for `nginx` user, and have it run from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed the permission of the folders. The error is" The page you were looking for doesn't exist." Nginx runs with user 'nginx', and i think 'nginx' and 'ec2-user' are both under ec2-user group, is it? see my edited. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you actually have `index.html` inside your `public` folder? What does nginx log say now?

Comment: I have others like '500.html', i think rails 3+ generate index.html default. But if i access 52.74.148.194/500.html still the same error. Nignx log still the same.

Comment: Please add `ls -l` output from your `current` and `public` folders to your question. And just to be sure, restart nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: Attached the permission of the folder, i restarted nginx everytime.

Comment: Now that is strange. Change `user nginx` in nginx config to `user ec2-user` and see if error still persists.

Comment: Just to make sure. `whoami` returns `ec2-user`, `ps -axu | grep nginx` show that nginx is run under ec2-user (first column), and `cat "/home/ec2-user/apps/mybest/current/public//index.html"` returns no error in terminal?

Comment: Yes, just the user issue, i changed '''ec2-user''' back to 'nginx', the error got back. Just wondering ec2-user and nginx are in the same group has no help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85120/discussion-between-william-hu-and-eugzol).

Comment: @WilliamHu You are welcome. Answered you in chat, and also updated my answer with the same information. If you like the answer you might consider upvoting it as well :)