# Unicorn and nginx (13: Permission denied)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

I am starting app with ngnix and unicorn, but in log nginx got this error

```
 *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 181.52.249.209, server: lovebeeroficial.com
```

I found similar error but Dont work for me, the file have all permission

I try this [Nginx failed (13: Permission denied) when start rails with unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791611/nginx-failed-13-permission-denied-when-start-rails-with-unicorn) 
and [Nginx getting Permission denied when connecting to Unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205263/nginx-getting-permission-denied-when-connecting-to-unicorn)

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 azureuser azureuser    1 Feb 24 07:43 unicorn.sock
```

Comment: I am follow this tutorial, what is the error https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 2):

`-rwxrwxrwx. 1 azureuser azureuser    1 Feb 24 07:43 unicorn.sock` - it doesn't looks like unix socket.
`srwxrwxrwx. 1 azureuser azureuser    1 Feb 24 07:43 unicorn.sock` - it should look like this.

You need to check where your unicorn stores socket really.

If you sure unicorn use `/tmp`, then `rm -rf /tmp/unicorn.sock` and restart unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

To check that the case is in SELinux, you can disable it

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

but it's not safe to turn it off, and the problem will return when you reboot

Good detailed article https://nts.strzibny.name/allowing-nginx-to-use-a-pumaunicorn-unix-socket-with-selinux/

In short, you need to execute the command and save the output to the nginx.te file

```
sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m nginx                                                                                                                        
                                                           
module nginx 1.0;                                          
                                                                
require {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        type httpd_t;                                           
        type initrc_t;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;              
}                                                         
                                                       
#============= httpd_t ==============                        
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

and then check, compile and subtract

```
sudo checkmodule -M -m -o nginx.mod nginx.te
sudo semodule_package -o nginx.pp -m nginx.mod
sudo semodule -i nginx.pp
```